# Why is Screen Recording disabled in QuickTime?

Tags: quicktime, screen-recording

Here we see that *Movie Recording* and *Audio Recording* are enabled, but *New Screen Recording* is not.  Why would this be?   I have stopped/restarted *QuickTime* several times now and this behavior persists.  I am on `macOS Ventura 13.3.1` so am quite up to date.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently a screen recording was actually underway.  I could not see the typical command-bar at the bottom of the screen. This was a recording mode I am unfamiliar with.

Comment: It would improve porove the answer by providing a *cropped* screen grab of the bottom of your screen so it’s clear what you’re referring to.

Comment: You can tell if the screen is recording, as an icon appears in the menubar -- it's a circle with a square inside.